# can NVL return different data type as its argument?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, nvl

in the following query,

`select NVL(gender, 'not available') from member`

I want the query returns 'Not Available' when gender is null. but it seems that the second argument has to be the same data type as first argument.(in this example gender is CHAR(1) but second argument is VARCHAR or CHAR(n) rather than CHAR(1). Is there any solution besides changing data type in main table?
I am using Amazon Redshift.
I am using the nvl statement in group by as well so I need the solution to be concise as much as possible.

Comment: What is the datatype of gender? What is the error? You can cast it to a string in the select rather than changing the column's type in the table.

Comment: This may well depend on DB used, please add tag for the relevant DBMS.

Comment: Use `coalesce()`.  It is the ANSI standard version and available in more databases.

Comment: I tried coalesce as well. it doesn't work in redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with case

```
select case gender when is null then 'not available' else gender 
from my_table
```

Comment: yes, it works but I want to use it in group by, is there any concise solution?

Comment: Well for  group by you should post a new proper described question  .. I can't imagine your problem by the actual question and is not fair change a question in another .. so if my answer is right please mark as accepted .. post the new question and eventually comment me the new link

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

find gender first (SELECT gender FROM member WHERE .....)

```
if gender is null
begin
select 'not available' as result
end
else
begin
<-- do your query-->
end
```

Comment: There is no `if` in SQL (and even if there was - where does `gender` come from? It's a column in a table)

Comment: he should find gender first (SELECT gender FROM member WHERE .....) than run that. i am sorry if there is no IF.